# How to add an anchor in React props?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a component like this:

```js
const Paragraph = ({content}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>
        {content}
      </p>
    </>
  )
}
```

I'd like to pass a mix of string and anchor into it, such as:

```
<Paragraph
  content={'Github page is <a href="https://github.com/">here</a>'}
/>
```

But it returned the anchor as a string. I tried string literals:

```
<Paragraph 
  content={`Github page is ${<a href="https://github.com/">here</a>}`}
/>
```

it returned `Github page is [Object Object]`

How can I make it show the correct anchor content?

Comment: You can't pass JSX or an HTML tag through props

Comment: The component may be contrived, but I'd just use a plain old `<p>` instead of creating a `Paragraph` wrapper which seems like a faux/useless abstraction. If the component is a stand-in for a more complex component, ignore this comment and check out the existing answers, or describe your use case a bit further if they don't do the job, or to disambiguate between them in terms of applicability to your use case.

Comment: @ggorlen probably just the case when you have a really long className for `<p>`? Like `<p className='section-title'></p>`, then making it into a component saves some typing.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is a generic box that you'd like to pass children to, so use `children` (read: [Containment](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment)):

```
const Paragraph = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>
        {children}
      </p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Then, simply pass JSX, not a template literal:

```
<Paragraph>
    Github page is <a href="https://github.com/">here</a>
</Paragraph>
```

If you're really set on using a prop called `content`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64772468/1612146) will do you just fine.

Sidenote: As it stands, the `React.Fragment` used in your `Paragraph` component is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

Use a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```js
<Paragraph
  content={<>Github page is <a href="https://github.com/">here</a></>}
/>
```